# What is a third syntax for declaring a property inside an anonymous?

Tags: c#, syntax, anonymous-types

What is a third syntax for declaring a property inside an anonymous?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book. And I come across the following excerpt (1):

> The compiler supports **two** additional syntaxes for declaring a property inside an anonymous type
>   where it can infer the property names and types from variables:

```
String Name = "Grant";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
// Anonymous type with two properties
// 1. String Name property set to Grant
// 2. Int32 Year property set to the year inside the dt
var o2 = new { Name, dt.Year };
```

While a few paragraphs back the author presented the following syntax for creating an anonymous type (2):

```
// Define a type, construct an instance of it, & initialize its properties
var o1 = new { Name = "Jeff", Year = 1964 };
```

So, from the above two excerpts I draw a conclusion that there is one syntax for declaring a property inside an anonymous type and two additional syntaxes for this. And while one of the additional syntaxes was presented in the book, I still do not see the second additional syntax being presented in the book.

I heard about the syntax and about the first additional syntax and I used them in a few occasions in my applications. But I can not remember using any other syntax (which would be the third).

All that makes me believe that there are actually only two syntaxes and the third (which is second additional) does not exist. And the excerpt presented above is just a mistake in the book: the author should have written

> ... supports <del>two</del> additional ...

Also, I was not able to find anything on the third syntax on the internet.

So, is it just a mistake or am I missing the third syntax here?

Comment: It's poorly worded. The "two additional" syntaxes are really just the same thing. It's using the identifier as the name of the property and it's showing two variations on how that works. In one case, the identifier is a local variable (`Name`). In the other, the identifier is a property accessed from a local variable (`dt.Year` but `Year` is the relevant identifier). So there are two syntaxes in total (not three), one where you assign a value an explicitly chosen property name and one where you implicitly use the existing identifier as the property name.

Comment: It's great that you're trying to learn the language so deeply. However, you're dealing with books written in a way that simplifies the language from the spec because practically no one will learn a language from a spec). If you want to learn it to that level, you need to go to the spec itself because that's the formal definition from which the compiler is written. Try taking a more practical approach rather than memorizing that there are N ways of doing something. You can "know" a lot but doing is much more important.

Comment: @madreflection, I am not memorizing anything here. I want to understand whether or not there is another way for the anonymous type initialization. Thank you a lot for the attention. Should I remove the question from your pov?

Comment: @madreflection, how would you recommend me approach the learning of the .net based web development? I believe that it is important to have a good theoretical knowledge of the CLR and C# at first, isn`t it?

Comment: As I mentioned, take a more practical approach. Don't get stuck "in the weeds". If you miss on an edge case or rarely used feature, it's not that important. Most C# programmers probably don't use 20-30% of the language (just a guess) on an average day, and some use even less. Learn to use the important parts and practice. Then add a little more every so often.

Comment: You can also use an expression to set the value of a property. That's not really a different syntax IMO but you might make a case for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> You create anonymous types by using the new operator together with an object initializer.

The object initializer syntax is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). It's this syntax:

```
{ PropertyName = value, ... }
```

And back on the anonymous type documentation:

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being used to initialize them.

So, there is only one syntax:

```
new {[PropertyName =] value, ...}
```

The `PropertyName =` part is optional if the value is a property. (What about fields?).

Like it was said in the comments, your source is poorly worded.